# Azure Devops inline bash script subshell output as variable to task group

Tags: bash, azure, azure-devops, azure-pipelines, azure-pipelines-release-pipeline

I have a task in an agent job on Azure DevOps that runs an inline bash script. Part of what it does is to read the content of a file and assign it to a variable:

`filecontent=$(<artifact/drop/myfile.txt)`

I want to make this task part of a task group, however when I create a task group from the task it is identifying `$(<artifact/drop/myfile.txt)` as a variable and automatically adding it to the list of variables for the task group.

[image]

Is there a way round this?

Answer (score 1):

Set the variable as follows:

```
filecontent=`cat artifact/drop/myfile.txt`
```